# Bug in sorting reputation history in profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, reputation-history

Sort by 'post' does not work in the list of reputation changes. When you press 'post' it is sorting it by 'time' instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort by post or by time is working daily only meaning sorting the list of **daily events** either by post or by time.

See the profile of anyone with more than one event in some days to see it working.

Jon Skeet is ultimate example (the day he won't have reputation events is more than impossible). [By time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time) and [by post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post).

Comment: "the day he won't have reputation events is more than impossible" no, all it needs is to take Stack Overflow offline for a day.

Comment: He will still gain more than the rep cap. Believe me! :D

Answer (score 3):

The reputation history is **always** divided into each day that reputation is gained, there's no getting around that. The difference between sorting by "time" and "post" is:

- Sorting by **time** lists all events separately in the order they occurred, under that day.
- Sorting by **post** groups all the events for each post together into one event with an expandable arrow to see all the events that make it up, sorting by the *latest* event in each group.

Comment: Walked away with a half-written answer, and I come back to see you've taken the words right out of my mouth.